# Secure LDAP Authentication in Java

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate and determine the appropriate permission set for a user in Java, using the active directory.

Does anyone have an example of a SECURE (password not being sent in clear text) LDAP authentication mechanism? I can't seem to find an appropriate example (I'm a visual learner).

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that uses LDAPS (LDAP over SSL/TLS) like this [tutorial](http://www.agile-works.com/blog/?p=447)?

Comment: Is this the only solution or are there others?

Comment: Sending a pre-encrypted or hashed password is not a good idea; the directory server may not be able to enforce password quality checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GSS-API to verify users authenticity.